# SHA1 hash question

Tags: c#, sha1

I have this method to hash a string:

```
 byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
 SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 =
                new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
 string hash = BitConverter.ToString(
                cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");

 return hash;
```

My question is:

Is the resulting hash always the same for the same string?

I hashed a string a couple of days ago and it seems that it now resulted in another hash, but i'm not sure.

Comment: You are not encrypting anything, you are hashing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: You can't tell with the provided code ... when you change enc from one encoding to another the hash would change, too. But I assume enc is fixed --> Ignacios answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the same plaintext string will hash to the same SHA1 hash every time.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the bytes are the same, you will end up with exactly the same hash. Note that special characters and whitespace are bytes as well.

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Id depends! The same plain text string will hash to the same SHA1 hash if you use the same Encoding! Using different Encoding will result in different SHA1 hash.